# nmcli con up: "Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found"

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli

I'm trying to connect to an already known network via console (to later put this into a script). The most promising command so far seemed to be this one:

```
nmcli con up "Weelaan" ifname wlp4s0
```

That at least turns my WLAN tray icon into a loading animation and it looks like it's trying to connect to the right network, but after a wile I get error notifications and this output:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=eef66f76-9566-4e3c-889c-9634960dd1b7 + NM_DEVICE=wlp4s0' to get more details.
```

Running that hinted command gives this output for the corresponding time:

```
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9017] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Weelaan' (eef66f76-9566-4e3c-889c-9634960dd1b7)
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9021] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9049] device (wlp4s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 28:C6:3F:B1:EA:27 (preserve)
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9095] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9100] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Weelaan' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9101] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9122] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9127] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9129] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Weelaan' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 26 10:21:24 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287684.9435] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 26 10:21:49 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <warn>  [1627287709.9959] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul 26 10:21:49 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287709.9959] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 10:21:49 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287709.9983] device (wlp4s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 26:28:CC:D2:10:A4 (scanning)
Jul 26 10:21:50 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <warn>  [1627287710.0022] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Weelaan'
Jul 26 10:21:50 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287710.0024] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul 26 10:21:50 manjaro NetworkManager[623]: <info>  [1627287710.0043] device (wlp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Simply clicking the network tray icon and then the "connect" button on the network works, but I don't want to take over the mouse in that script. That would also make it dependant on screen resolution and would have many other undesirable side effects. So what is `nmcli`'s issue and how do I resolve this? What does it even do differently from KDE's network menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to execute `nmcli device wifi rescan` first, even if that network is already known and already appears in the visible networks list.